# How to make Abiword default in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, default-programs, abiword

In earlier releases I could do that by right-clicking on a document file, going to Properties -> Open With and selecting Abiword, but in 11.10 I can't see Abiword as an option. How can I now make it the default application for opening my doc/docx files?

[image: Screenshot of file properties' Open With tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try installing ubuntu-tweak http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ In Admins->File Type Manager in **Text** and **Program** Section select the filetypes that you want to change to handle with Abiword

Comment: Awesome! I already had Ubuntu tweak for its Janitor function but never ventured into other "tweaks" it stores. Your suggestion answered my query..Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to click the Add button and add the executable's path.

See, `xxx@linux-dopx:~/> which oocalc` gives me `/usr/bin/oocalc` This path if added by the Add button will appear in that list, and then you can select it.

Comment: but in that image, the add button is grayed out. :-( I always much prefer Abiword and Gnumeric over Libre or Open Office. The fact that Libre has the truely open source aspect is great, but it sticks out like a soar thumb lol hopefully the Libre team will be able to make it look a little more native and pretty looking in coming versions.

Comment: @DanielClem You said: `but in that image, the add button is grayed out.` Perhaps because the root permissions are needed?

Comment: Well I really dunno lol Maybe launching Nautilus as root using 'gksu nautilus' and then opening the preferences of the file and doing the same thing?? As a very new user, I was just starting to catch onto stuff like that back in Maverick 10.10, but now it seems all this stuff is changing. I would try and test it, but I'm using Xubuntu which uses slightly different apps for most stuff. Its annoyingly inconsistent. But doesn't have Unity, and is so much more customizable.